# Startup Project keeps reverting to IIS Express for debugging

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-express

In my solution I basically have two projects, the one I'm coding on, and the startup project, `Startup.csproj`. I have `Startup.csproj` configured to use `Local IIS` for debugging, and I normally just attach to the worker process to debug.

However, at random intervals, the `Startup.csproj` defaults back to IIS Express for debugging. It does not show as a change in the `Startup.csproj` project file, and sometimes even still shows `Local IIS` but fails with a "Cannot list contents of directory" error.

I'm running VS 2017 v15.9.15. What could be causing this annoying little phenomenon?

Comment: Does the IIS change between opening/closing the project, or is it between builds that it changes?

Comment: @Coffee It changes between builds, or rather between runs, but I nearly always run after a build, so I'm not quite sure where the change happens, but it's not only on closing and opening the project.

Comment: I was thinking it might be similar to something that happened to me before where VS kept re-generating my .csproj file which was in turn setting my <UseIISExpress>false</UseIISExpress> flag to true

Comment: What do you have under Properties\launchSettings.json

Comment: @Iain It is not a Core project, just plain .NET Framework. I don't have any `launchSettings.json`.

Comment: @ProfK Did you ever fix this issue? I inherited a project that does the exact same thing. While it's not the biggest deal it drives me slightly insane.

Comment: @MirceaIon Unfortunately I never fixed the issue, and can't remember what the outcome was - I think an upgrade to VS2019, or the problem just went away.

Comment: @ProfK Half hour later I found what the problem was and posted a response, if not for you for eternity (however long that will be). Than I noticed someone actually made a comment above which was basically a lead to same solution.

Answer (score 12):

I thought I am going crazy. I found the settings driving that behavior in the project file. I set the **UseIISExpress** to 'false' and the other one all the way at the end of the file project **UseIIS** to 'true' and when reloading still set to use IISExpress.

Turns out there's a <*ProjectFile*>.csproj.user that will overwrite default settings. Search for the UseIISExpress in this file and set it to false and Voila! problem solved.

Comment: very intuitive. thanks, MSFT! /s

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Restart your IIS and try as above
and go to the root directory and delete .vs directory if exists.
or
In the Processes window (Debug -> Windows -> Processes), right-click on the name of the process you want to detach, and on the shortcut menu, click Detach Process.:

Comment: Are you saying that detaching from the process will reset my project setting back to `Local IIS` from `IIS Express`, or merely fix the link VS has to my IIS virtual folder?

Answer (score 0):

Another scenario may be that the port that IIS is using for your application is already being used by another running application. Try changing the port and see if it works for you.

Comment: I'm using straight port 80 and attaching to the `w3wp.exe` process. I have no other applications at all in IIS - this was the first one ever added, to the Default Web Site.